# JScrollPane with scroll bar to left

Tags: java, swing

I need to place a scroll bar to the *left* of the contents in my JScrollPane. Can it be done without a separate JScrollBar component? Perhaps simply by setting some alignment?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using trial and error I found that

```
JScrollPane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

worked like a charm.

Comment: Nice. Did this have any other effects that you noticed?

Comment: Works. But both (vertical and horizontal) scrollbars are then from 'right to left'. This also means that the horizontal scrollbar scrolls completely to the right which may cut some text if there is not enough space. This feels at least a little bit strange.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer gade my `GridBagLayout` panel inability to stretch horizontally (and it seems there is more to it with components' preferred size bug [#5727254](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5727254/4618338))

I found solution for this:

```
leftPanelScroll.setRowHeaderView(leftPanelScroll.getVerticalScrollBar());
```

I hope it will help yet another poor soul.

Answer (score -4):

I tried changing the alignment of the track div from 'right' to 'left' in the css class `.jspVerticalBar`. seems to work.

```
.jspVerticalBar
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 16px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: With the tags I wanted to indicate that the question is about Java Swing (not JavaScript).