# Swing JScrollPane - how to set vertical scroll bar to left?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

See the title. I've tried to change component orientation to `RIGHT_TO_LEFT`, but that had a unexpected side effect - it behaves strangely with components with specified preferred size.

(JDK 1.6.0_23, Eclipse VE)

**EDIT**

Here is the example of this:

We have `JFrame` with `jMainScrollPane` on it. Inside `jMainScrollPane` we place a `jMainPanel`. Now set `jMainPanel`'s preferred size to be narrower than `jMainScrollPane`'s. `jMainPanel` will still take all the space on `jMainScrollPane`. Now change`jMainScrollPane`'s orientation to `RIGHT_TO_LEFT` and see what happen.

Sample code (change `jMainScrollPane`'s orientation to see the difference):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {
    private JPanel      jContentPane    = null;
    private JScrollPane jMainScrollPane = null;
    private JPanel      jMainPanel      = null;
    
    public TestFrame(){
        super();
        initialize();
    }
    
    private void initialize(){
        this.setSize(480, 339);
        this.setContentPane(getJContentPane());
        this.setTitle("JFrame");
    }
    
    private JPanel getJContentPane(){
        if (jContentPane == null) {
            jContentPane = new JPanel();
            jContentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            jContentPane.add(getJMainScrollPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
        return jContentPane;
    }
    
    private JScrollPane getJMainScrollPane(){
        if (jMainScrollPane == null) {
            jMainScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
            jMainScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            jMainScrollPane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
            jMainScrollPane.setViewportView(getJMainPanel());
        }
        return jMainScrollPane;
    }
    
    private JPanel getJMainPanel(){
        if (jMainPanel == null) {
            jMainPanel = new JPanel();
            jMainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            jMainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
        }
        return jMainPanel;
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

Due to the strange nature of this, I've submitted a bug to Oracle. They mailed me a bug link

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7038455

At the moment there is no such bug yet - I suppose, it's being checked.

But still, question is open - is there a workaround or another way?

Comment: Duplicate of [JScrollPane with scroll bar to left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311689/jscrollpane-with-scroll-bar-to-left)

Comment: @Manoj seems like @Frozen_Spider already tried the answer of mentionned question, but was not satisfied with result.

Comment: @Frozen_Spider when you write "ruined layout inside of it.", can you tell us what you mean ? Or send a screenshot ?

Comment: I agree. The given solution should work. I've tested it on a `JTable` with a `JScrollpane`. the `JScrollpane` doesn't have any preferred size set.

Comment: I can't provide you a code sample nor a screenshot right now. Could you please be patient and wait until tomorrow?

Comment: Added source code. Is it a bug?

Comment: I notice that you have two `JScrollPane`s...the main one views the `jMainPanel` and the second one views nothing. Why are you designing like that? If your intention is to trigger vertical scroll bar for the `jMainPanel`, you just need `JMainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));` and remove the need for the second `JScrollPane` which I don't see a purpose.

Comment: good idea to report a bug (see my answer for a partial track down) - could you add the report id? The inital from the automatic response is good enough, will try a little pushing ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with the OP: it's bug. The setting of RToL orientation triggers the calculation of the viewPosition. This happens *before* the layout is done. In that case, the JViewport returns the view's preferredSize instead of its actual size (which at that time is zero). Deep in the bowels, the BasicScrollPaneUI.Handler doesn't know about that faked size and bases its calculation on incorrect data.

Here's some code to play with (the OPs original stripped down a bit further, added colored borders to see where is what):

```
public class COInScrollPane extends JFrame {

    public COInScrollPane(){
        super();
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize(){
        this.setTitle("JFrame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JScrollPane jMainScrollPane = getJMainScrollPane();
        this.add(jMainScrollPane);
        this.setSize(480, 339);
        Action action = new AbstractAction("Toggle CO") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ComponentOrientation co = jMainScrollPane.getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight() ?
                        ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT : ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT;
                jMainScrollPane.applyComponentOrientation(co);
                jMainScrollPane.revalidate();
                jMainScrollPane.repaint();
            }
        };
        add(new JButton(action), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private JScrollPane getJMainScrollPane() {
        JScrollPane jMainScrollPane = new JScrollPane(getJMainPanel());
        jMainScrollPane.setViewportBorder(BorderFactory
                .createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
        jMainScrollPane
                .applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        return jMainScrollPane;
    }

    private JPanel getJMainPanel() {
        JPanel jMainPanel = new JPanel();
        jMainPanel.add(new JButton("just a button"));
        jMainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        return jMainPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new COInScrollPane().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The initial layout is completely wrong (as reported by OP), toggle the CO with the button twice - the Layout looks okay.

A quick and dirty hack might be to do just that in procduction context: after initial layout, force the CO into LToR to allow for correct coordinates then back to RToL.

Comment: Thank you, dirty hack works :) I've also posted a bug link, but - shame on me - I described a bug far worst then you did.

Comment: @Frozen Spider glad it works for you :-) What's the review id (the number on the automatic bug response)?

Comment: What is so secret about this bug anyway... `Some bugs are not included in the Bug Database for security reasons.`

Comment: Anyway, it has been reported before http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4845945

Comment: Bug ID is posted at the bottom of a question: `7038455`

@eee: It seems, you right. Well, I'm just glad they know about it.

Comment: Thanks to Oracle, the 7038455 bug above no longer exists, and the 4845945 bug is commented with (1) a discussion link that's 404, (2) a note that "should be fixed in next release," and then (3) merely closed with "won't fix" and no further information why.  Sigh.