# Move Java swing scrollbar to the left side

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Swing JScrollPane - how to set vertical scroll bar to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727254/swing-jscrollpane-how-to-set-vertical-scroll-bar-to-left)

How can I move the vertical ScrollBar in a javax.swing.JScrollPane to the left side of the window?

Comment: that only possible by using Mouse, but programatically you have to look how to move with JViewport (visible part of JScrollPane)

Comment: Take a look at `JViewport.setViewPosition`.

Comment: `scrollpane.setRowHeaderView(scrollpane.getVerticalScrollBar());`