# Change position of a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, left-to-right

I got a sidebar, that are contained in a `JScrollPane` (as seen in picture below). However, I want the scroll pane to appear in the left side of the sidebar.

How i want it to be: (ScorllBar in the left)

[image]

How it is: (ScrollBar in the right)

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand, do you want the scroll bar to be on the left? As I read it currently the question asks how can the parent be on left of it's child (which is kinda meaningless)

Comment: @Ordous Added a new picture.. Hopefully you understand it now :)

Comment: @Ordous And yes, i need the ScrollBar to be in the left :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JScrollPane with scroll bar to left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311689/jscrollpane-with-scroll-bar-to-left)